# Finding elasticity coefficients dummy variables

Tags: regression, elasticity

Lnyt=3.493+0.231xt-0.13Dtxt+1.024D2-0.541D3+t

The data is quarterly and D2 and D3 are significant seasonal dummy variables I included. Additionally, Dtxt is the slope interaction dummy variable.

Xt is a time-trend variable (1,2,3 etc). It is unknown what the actual data represents.

How am I supposed to find the elastic effect of xt on yt when there are dummy variables? I have been instructed to calculate it using xt sample mean.